# evaluating angularjs ng-click parameters after angular has loaded all content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple jade markup as -

```
.well(ng-repeat="note in notes")
            .row
                h3.pull-left {{note.title}}
                p.pull-right ( {{note.subject}}, {{note.college}} )
            .row.margin-bottom-10(style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000")
                p.pull-left Author: {{note.author}}
                p.pull-right Uploaded by: {{note.uploader}}
            .row
                p.
                    {{note.description}}
            .row
                button.btn.btn-default.pull-left(ng-click="download('{{note.noteId}}','all')") Download
                button.btn.btn-default.pull-right Details
```

Now this gets converted to the following html in my website -

```
<div ng-repeat="note in notes" class="well ng-scope">
   <div class="row">
      <h3 class="pull-left ng-binding">test</h3>
      <p class="pull-right ng-binding">( test, MSRIT )</p></div>
   <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000" class="row margin-bottom-10">
      <p class="pull-left ng-binding">Author: test</p>
      <p class="pull-right ng-binding">Uploaded by: harshitladdha93@gmail.com</p></div>      
   <div class="row">
      <p class="ng-binding">test</p></div>
   <div class="row">
      <button ng-click="download('5f4815f2-73a9-4621-86ed-b4e302cc49ba','all')" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Download</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Details</button></div></div>
```

so from what i see here is that the `{{note.noteId}}` gets converted to `"5f4815f2-73a9-4621-86ed-b4e302cc49ba"` in the `ng-click="download()"` function of mine
but in my controller if i try -

```
$scope.download = function(noteId,fileId){
      var url = '/download/' + noteId + '/' + fileId;
};
```

I get

```
/download/{{note.noteId}}/all
```

that is `{{note.noteId}}` instead of the value processed by angular
how should i fix this

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces {{ }} wrapping around note.noteId from the jade template in order to make it work so it will be:

```
button.btn.btn-default.pull-left(ng-click="download(note.noteId,'all')") Download
```

Comment: No in such a case, I don't even get the noteId value in html only the note.noteId is printed in html and controller both

Comment: i do the same, and my ng-click looks like: `data-ng-click="download(note)"` and i get the `note` as object in the download function in my controller

Comment: Your Html markup should look something like this to work http://jsfiddle.net/tWQ7M/. Note: note is in angular scope right?

Comment: Yes, note is in angular and that's how all other values are getting retrieved. but for some reason I do see the url in the calling function but I don't see that url in the controller, my best guess is controller is loading that function before it evaluates the note.noteId for some reason

Comment: It should not decode the note.noteId in html and it should be download(note.noteId,'all') in the html markup so that Angular can evaluate that using the scope binding.